# Why is it called rebasing onto master when it's the other branch that's changing?

Tags: git, branch, rebase

This might be a silly semantics question but I'm asking anyway in case I'm not looking at this from the right perspective.

Let's say I have a simple repository with a master and feature branch - feature has a single commit, after which a commit for a Hotfix was added to master:

```
* 8aa11d5 (HEAD -> master) Hotfix
| * 73f496e (feature) Feature Added
|/
* d9588fc Initial File
```

I then rebase "feature onto master" by performing "git rebase master feature", which results in the following:

```
* aeaafd0 (feature) Feature Added, 'rebased onto master'
* 8aa11d5 (HEAD -> master) Hotfix
* d9588fc Initial File
```

At this point the only branch that has changed is feature, since I've incorporated the hotfix commit from master into it. Why then is this operation called "rebasing onto master" in the git docs and in online articles? Your immediate response may be "it's because when you then merge feature into master the commit chain will appear as if the feature commits were grafted onto master". I agree with that, which results in the following:

```
* aeaafd0 (HEAD -> master, feature) Feature Added, 'rebased onto master'
* 8aa11d5 Hotfix
* d9588fc Initial File
```

However, at the point in time I performed the rebase this wasn't true. The rebase certainly created a commit that links to the master tip, such that if I merge the two branches (fast-foward merge) then yes, I've rebased + merged onto master. In other words, the terminology of "rebasing onto master" implies a future operation that hasn't already happened.

Is this terminology used because it's assumed a merge will always logically follow the rebase? Or is it because I'm looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: Because you've moved `feature` from its old "base" (`d9588fc`) to a *new* base (`8aa11d5`, aka `master`).

Answer (score 3):

Because the commit pointed to by `master` is where the new rebased history will be built by adding commits "on top of" it. There's no implication that you're changing the named branch, because that argument doesn't even have to *be* a branch, it just names a commit. You're just picking up a piece of history and putting it down somewhere else.

Comment: Understood, but after the rebase (and before a likely merge) the master pointer hasn't changed. So performing commits to master after the rebase aren't affected by the rebase, unless and until feature is later merged into master. Again, it's a question of semantics - why is the term assuming a future event/operation that's separate and severable from the original operation, even if granted that future event/operation is the most likely outcome?

Comment: @Horshack it isn't. Rebasing onto master doesn't change the tip of master any more than putting a glass onto a table changes the location of the top of the table.

Comment: @Hoobs, A table's sole utility is to have items placed onto it so I don't think the connotations are comparable. In the rebase context 'onto' to me implies the target is being modified. If in an unrelated git context I said "I merged feature onto master" the listener would assume I meant master has changed, ie I merged feature into master. Maybe I just need to accept that "onto" doesn't imply what I expect it to here.

Comment: @Horshack: but nobody says "I merged X onto Y", the used terminology here is "I merged X into Y" (onto vs. into). When you rebase a branch, you take its commits and you place them _onto_ another commit – only the branch which is being rebased is modified. I think the table metaphor of hoobs is quite fitting. The feature branch is the glass and the master branch is the table. The glass might have been placed on a shelf before, so you'd say `git rebase --onto table shelf glass` (take glass off of the shelf and place it onto the table)

Comment: @knittl, I don't think the physical table metaphor fits. When you put something onto a table you make addition to that table. When you rebase feature onto master you're simply pointing to it - master is unchanged, nothing has been added to it. The only way for feature to be added to master is to merge after the rebase - that puts the glass on the table. And without that merge what happens if you add a commit to master - is feature still on top of master? That would be like saying I put a glass on the table and then replaced the top of the table..and claiming the glass is still on the table.

Comment: @Horshack then I'm afraid we will not be able to help you. If all you are looking for is confirmation of your own opininion, then Stackoverflow might not be the right format. One last attempt coming back to the metaphor: I still think it fits. Putting a glass *on top* of a table does _not_ magically make the glass "part of" the table. If you glue the glass to the table, that could be seen as merging. As to "committing to master": that's akin to placing something else onto the table, such as a plate. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] When executing the `rebase` subcommand, you are not specifying branches (with the exclusion of the last argument in the 2 or 3 argument-form), in fact you are specifying rev-specs pointing to a commit. Therefore, changing the `--onto` branch afterwards does not affect the rebased result, because it was executed against the commits, not the branches.

Comment: @knittl, I'm looking for well-reasoned arguments against my question, not confirmation. All have been earnest responses, which are appreciated, but they still overlook the core semantic premise of my question. A rebase places feature onto a facsimile of master, with the result placed in feature rather than onto the actual master. Only after a merge will feature be on top of the actual master. For the glass metaphor it would be claiming that placing a glass onto a photograph of the table is placing the glass onto the table, without disclosing it's a photograph rather than the actual table.

Comment: @Horshack the premise is flawed. Nowhere does it say that the "onto" part of the rebase modifies or changes the new base. It only says "take A from B and place it _on top of_ C" (`rebase --onto C B A`). Never is "A integrated 'into' C" nor "C 'fused' with A". It's a purely  topological transplant. Back to your example: The result is placed in feature because you are rebasing feature. You are not doing anything with master (master is just a rev-spec pointing to the latest commit). Feature is _topologically_ on top of master, master exists independently of feature, and master is never changed. …

Comment: … `master` is a pointer to a commit. You rebase **onto** that _commit_ pointed to by `master`. I don't see how a photograph of a table would be equivalent to a table? When you put something on top of a table, you put it onto the table (and not a clone of the table). But the table is still a table and not suddenly a table-with-glass-on-top. You can then put other stuff on the glass – a cover maybe? Or you can put other stuff onto the table – a plate or cutlery. Or you could take the glass again and move it somewhere else `--onto kitchen-sink`. Master (i.e. the "table") is never modified once.

Comment: @Horshack yeah. You asked for why it's called that, you got an answer. I can't make you *believe* it :)

Comment: @knittl, That's the crux of the argument - the word "onto" implies an action on the target of the preposition. If I said I was putting the contents of a string named 'feature' onto a string named 'master', would you not assume the string 'master' is being altered or affected? By git's rebase description it actually means adding the string 'feature' onto string 'master' but storing the result in 'feature'. That makes no sense. It's naming the action after an intermediate step rather than the outcome.

Comment: @Horshack I don't think so. To me the wording is perfectly clear. Putting something "onto" a table does not change the table itself. You can still put other stuff "onto" the table and it goes where I'd expect it to go. "put glass onto table", "put plate onto table", "put cutlery onto table" puts all those things directly onto the table and _does not_ stack them, i.e. you get table->glass, table->plate, table->cutlery and **not** table->glass->plate->cutlery. English is not my first language, so maybe I'm misunderstanding the word "onto"?

Comment: @knittl, When you look at a table after a glass has been placed onto it you see a table with a glass on it. When you look at master after feature has been reabsed onto it you still only see master. There's no hint of feature. Btw, your writing is fantastic for English not being your first language.

Comment: @Horshack no, when you look at the table, you see a table. Only when you look at the table and glass simultaneously, you see a table with a glass on it. The table exists independently of the glass and you can look at it without the glass (e.g. from the bottom; by blocking the view to the glass). But this is becoming rather philosophical :) `git rebase` transplants commits on top of another commit and uses the term "onto" to describe this movement to a new location in the DAG. I cannot explain it in another way, sorry. "onto" expects the location, it does not specify the target of the action.